# Angular Mat-form-field like component

Tags: angular, typescript, design-patterns, architecture

Hey Angular devs I'm trying to create reusable composable components something like Material mat-form-field and inside of it few predefined components that communicate together internaly.

I want to achieve something like this:

```
1)
<app-settings [formControl]="settingsForm" [options]="options">
  <app-text-settings />
</app-settings>

2)
<app-settings [formControl]="settingsForm" [options]="options">
  <app-video-settings />
</app-settings>
```

The app-settings component will have the logic for shared stuff like a base class and the components inside will extend it by adding it's own functionality on top of it. And they should share data without input outputs between each other just like the mat-form-field that can have inside many different form controls.

I can't find information about this. Do you know a good recourse that explains it? Also, what's this pattern called?

Comment: You have a guide in the [docs](https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control). Basically is create a custom form control that implements ControlValueAccessor (see, e.g. [this link](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-custom-form-controls/))and add some another properties. NOTE: See always if you want create a custom form control or, for your requeriments you can "solve" simply using child and viewProviders. A custom form controls should use only if we need an "especial" input, not for group a serie of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the ControlValueAccessor Interface to implement.

More information:
[Angular Doc](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor)

From YT:
[YT-Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OrmIfW8Ak3w)